# Illegal Character; Space is not Allowed

Tags: character, space

I am trying to validate my website and I am unable to solve this. This is the error I get:

```
**Bad value https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://www.company.com/blog/post/back-to-running/&t=Back to Running for attribute href on element a: Illegal character in query: space is not allowed.**
```

Where is the space I am supposed to fix? I tried `%20`, `%2F` and a bunch of other unicode but everything I tried broke my blog. Also got errors related to XML. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<a class="tweet" target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/share?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.company.com%2Fblog%2Fpost%2Fback-to-running%2F" title="Tweet This"></a>
<a class="facebook" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://www.snapediting.com/blog/post/back-to-running/&t=Back to Running" title="Share on Facebook"></a>
```

Comment: Maybe they are referring to this part `Back to Running`!

Comment: That address is auto-populated so I am not sure how I am supposed to encode those spaces. The Twitter one auto-populates with %2F...

Comment: Ok I see that should be in the question as it would be confusing

Answer (score 2):

Try to fix

```
back-to-running/&t=Back to Running
```

to

```
back-to-running/&t=Back%20to%20Running
```

if not working, use "+":

```
back-to-running/&t=Back+to+Running
```

Comment: That address is not hand coded in. Here is the back-end code:  <a class="tweet" target="_blank" href="<?php echo Post::tweet_link() ?>" title="Tweet This"></a><a class="facebook" target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php echo Post::permalink(true) ?>&t=<?php echo Post::title() ?>" title="Share on Facebook"></a>